# kafka image build kompose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

How do we build a kafka image and then deploy it to kubernetes through the Kompose tool?

I was using this docker-compose.yml file. It works with docker-compose to build a kafka image. But when we use Kompose, which converts docker-compose.yml to kubernetes service, pvc, and deployments, not having the pre-built image is causing issues.

Building kafka image, then referencing it in the yml file also causes issues. 
Lastly, I am not able to mount volumes.

How can I fix these issues? Thank you

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: myIP
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    links:
    - zookeeper:zk
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  myApp:
    image: myAppImage
    ports:
      - "3904:3904"
      - "3905:3905"
    volumes:
      - /var/tmp/My.properties:/appl/myApp/bundleconfig/etc/appprops/My.properties
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
```

download-kafka.sh file

```
    #!/bin/sh

mirror=$(curl --stderr /dev/null https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi\?as_json\=1 | jq -r '.preferred')
url="${mirror}kafka/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz"
wget -q "${url}" -O "/tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz"
```

start-kafka.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$KAFKA_PORT" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_PORT=9092
fi
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=$(docker port `hostname` $KAFKA_PORT | sed -r "s/.*:(.*)/\1/g")
fi
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_BROKER_ID" ]]; then
    # By default auto allocate broker ID
    export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
fi
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_LOG_DIRS" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_LOG_DIRS="/kafka/kafka-logs-$HOSTNAME"
fi
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=$(env | grep ZK.*PORT_2181_TCP= | sed -e 's|.*tcp://||' | paste -sd ,)
fi

if [[ -n "$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" ]]; then
    sed -r -i "s/(export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS)=\"(.*)\"/\1=\"$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS\"/g" $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh
    unset KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
fi

if [[ -z "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME" && -n "$HOSTNAME_COMMAND" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$(eval $HOSTNAME_COMMAND)
fi

for VAR in `env`
do
  if [[ $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_ && ! $VAR =~ ^KAFKA_HOME ]]; then
    kafka_name=`echo "$VAR" | sed -r "s/KAFKA_(.*)=.*/\1/g" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr _ .`
    env_var=`echo "$VAR" | sed -r "s/(.*)=.*/\1/g"`
    if egrep -q "(^|^#)$kafka_name=" $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties; then
        sed -r -i "s@(^|^#)($kafka_name)=(.*)@\2=${!env_var}@g" $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties #note that no config values may contain an '@' char
    else
        echo "$kafka_name=${!env_var}" >> $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
    fi
  fi
done

if [[ -n "$CUSTOM_INIT_SCRIPT" ]] ; then
  eval $CUSTOM_INIT_SCRIPT
fi


KAFKA_PID=0

# see https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.bh35ir4u5
term_handler() {
  echo 'Stopping Kafka....'
  if [ $KAFKA_PID -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -s TERM "$KAFKA_PID"
    wait "$KAFKA_PID"
  fi
  echo 'Kafka stopped.'
  exit
}


# Capture kill requests to stop properly
trap "term_handler" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
create-topics.sh &
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties &
KAFKA_PID=$!
```

Answer (score 0):

### Image issues

**Step 1**: Do `docker-compose build` and you will have a `kafka` image that you can use to deploy on the Kubernetes. But to enable Kubernetes to pull this image either push it docker hub or some private docker registry from where your Kubernetes cluster can pull images.

Note the name of the docker image from the above step since that is needed in step below.

Also if you push the image to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) it will be named as `docker.io/yourUserName/imageName` but if you push to some other docker registry it will be named differently.

**Step 2**: You have to change the docker-compose file in the `kafka` service to include the image name you gave above. This is an [issue](https://github.com/Kubernetes-incubator/kompose/issues/571) in kompose where in it should error out since the image name is not given and kompose cannot magically give some image name in the generated Kubernetes config.

So change it to something like this

```
  kafka:
    build: .
    image: docker.io/username/mykafka:0.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
```

**Step 3**: Once you add that image name you will have a valid Kubernetes config generated by kompose with the image name you have provided.

Now you can try to deploy the application and Kubernetes will be able to pull the image just fine.

If you are doing this in a single node cluster like minikube there is a easy workaround you can follow as mentioned in this [blog](http://suraj.io/post/enabling-local-development-with-k8s/).

### Volume issues

- With Kubernetes it is not recommended to do host mounts
- Also I am not sure what is the best way to mount docker socket with Kubernetes.
- Also since this container needs docker socket kind of mount you will need to start this in privileged mode which is not recommended at all.
- The ideal way to share configurations in Kubernetes is not via host based volume mounts but via Kubernetes object called [`configMaps`](https://Kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/)